# R - lattice plot. Separate lines for levels of a factor

Tags: r, lattice

With `xyplot` from the `lattice` package, I can produce a scatterplot of y ~ x disaggregated into separate panels by factors (e.g., f1 and f2) with `xyplot(y ~ x|f1*f2, data=d)`. I would like to change that so that the panels relate to values of f1 but within each panel there are separate lines y~x on each level of factor f2. I assume that it would be possible by changing the panel= option but I cannot see how to do it.

I think that this question has probably been asked before but in a different way ... resulting in me being unable to find anything!

Comment: It would help if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. I'm guessing you want `xyplot(y ~ x|f1, groups=f2, data=d)` but it's somewhat unclear.

Comment: @MrFlick Your guess was spot-on; your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. If you enter it as the answer (instead of a comment) I'll mark it as correct.